# copy elements from one array to another array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I like to copy the array A elements to Array B elements with specific

example :

```
array A=[0123]        
array  b=[1111111111111111111]
```

i want `b=[1111111101231111111]

```
int ip=0;                        
[b addObjectsFromArray:[A objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSetindexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(ip, 10)]]];
```

i know how to copy the array element , i want to know how to replace the object start from 9 to 13 in array b to  replaced by array a element , can any give me hint

Comment: Why do you use the iPhone tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    NSArray *a = @[@0,@1,@2,@3];
    NSArray *b = @[@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1,@1];

    NSMutableArray *c = [b mutableCopy];
    // The range here is index->8 (9th object) and length->4
    [c replaceObjectsInRange:NSMakeRange(8,4) withObjectsFromArray:a];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create mutable copy of your array and modify them:

```
NSMutableArray* mutableArray = [yourArray mutableCopy];
```

Then you will access to this methods: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: hi i am using nsmutable array only. i can copy the array A  but i want to replace that into array b between 9 to 13